# User login with groups

Tags: php, authentication

I have **one login** form and **three groups** of users who can login: client, member, admin. All users share some common attributes, like username, password, active.
Most of the other fields are different for the respective group, with the table member having up to 30 fields.

This is the reason I would rather not have one large user table with all the needed fields, but separate the group related fields to different tables. 
I would then have following tables:

```
------------------
| tbl_user       |
|----------------|
| id             |
| username       |
| password       |
| active         |
------------------

------------------
| tbl_client     |
|----------------|
| id             |
| pid            |
| company        |
| address        |
| projects       |
| ...            |
------------------

... same with tbl_member and tbl_admin.
```

But after the login, how can I select the additional fields from either tbl_client, tbl_member and tbl_admin?
I could use a group field in tbl_user and use the group table name as the value. But that doesn't seem very professional ;)

Any other ideas?

Comment: Thank you all for convincing me to use a a tbl_user.group field to specify the user goup (client, member, admin) and join the tables tbl_user.id on tbl_*.pid.

I tried accepting all answers, unfortunately only one was possible, so I chose the first one from Ryan Bates. But thanks to TheCapn, Dalton Conley and Jim as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you suggested is a perfectly acceptable solution - `tbl_user` needs to identify the user type in some way, somehow. You could swap out the string for an `id`, if that may be easier to work with. After you determine the user type, you can then simply join with whichever detail table is applicable, or query the detail table directly.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why you say "it doesn't seem professional". You're separating the user data role from the user authentication information as you should. There's nothing wrong with what you suggested and I would recommend it...

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest adding another column in `tbl_user` that states what type of account it is. e.g. admin, member, client, that way you can direct them to whatever you need after they have logged in, and you can pull their information.

Answer (score 1):

You could do an outter join on all three tables.

This will return results of all three tables, two of which will have null results (as they don't exist). This is less efficient as you are joining four tables (user, member, client, admin), then adding an additional field to specificy which group the member is a part of, and querying only that table with some logic.